# SQLAlchemy: getter/setter in declarative Mixin class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to define simple getter/setter methods for a mixin class that I intend to use in my database schema:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import synonym, scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


class Mixin(object):
    _attr = Column('attr', Integer)

    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, value):
        self._attr = value

    attr = synonym('_attr', descriptor=attr)


class DummyClass(Base, Mixin):
    __tablename__ = 'dummy'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    session = Session()
    testobj = DummyClass()
    session.add(testobj)
    testobj.attr = 42
    assert testobj.attr == 42
```

When I try to run this example, I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Mapper properties (i.e. deferred,column_property(), relationship(), etc.) must be declared as @declared_attr callables on declarative mixin classes.`

My code is almost a 1:1 copy from the [SQLAlchemy Declarative Tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html#defining-synonyms), with the only difference that the property/synonym is declared in a Mixin class. Appending or prepending the "@declared_attr" decorator to the existing decorators does not change anything.

How do I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps create the `attr()` as an `@declared_attr`-decorated class method which returns the synonym?

```
class Mixin(object):

    _attr = Column('attr', Integer)

    def get_attr(self):
        return self._attr

    def set_attr(self, value):
         self._attr = value

    @declared_attr
    def attr(cls):
        return synonym('_attr', descriptor=property(cls.get_attr, cls.set_attr))
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick :-) This is what happens if you rely too much on the syntactic sugar and don't learn how to do without it :3

Comment: won't work if that column is a foreign key :( *Columns with foreign keys to other columns must be declared as @declared_attr callables*

Answer (score -1):

```
@contact.setter
def contact_id(self, contact_id):
    if (contact_id is None):
        raise ValueError('contact_id can only be a uuid string')

    if not isinstance(contact_id, str):
        raise TypeError('contact_id is not a string')

    self._contact_id = contact_id
```

With a setter the code above can throw a much more clearer error
than what PyAlchemy can throw at you.

You might also choose to gracefully handle the error in production if possible.