# Synonyms in declarative mixin classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use synonyms in a mix in for a declarative class model.

```
class MyMixin(object):

    __my_field = Column(Boolean, name='my_field', index=True, default=True)

    def __get_my_field(self):
        return self.__my_field

    @declared_attr
    def my_field(cls):  # @NoSelf
        return synonym('__my_field', descriptor=property(cls.__get_my_field))    


Base = declarative_base(cls=MyMixin)


class Model(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'model'

    value = Column(String)
```

The code starts up fine, but whenever I try to query on that field (`session.query(Model).filter(Model.my_field==True)`), I get a maximum recursion error.

I've tried the solution suggested [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821947/sqlalchemy-getter-setter-in-declarative-mixin-class), but all I get is a Maximum Recursion Exceeded error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python applies [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) to class attributes that start with a double underscore, and I *strongly* suspect that that is the root of your problem here.

Remove one of the underscores from your column declaration:

```
class MyMixin(object):

    __my_field = Column(Boolean, name='my_field', index=True, default=True)

    def _get_my_field(self):
        return self._my_field

    @declared_attr
    def my_field(cls):  # @NoSelf
        return synonym('_my_field', descriptor=property(cls._get_my_field))
```

Comment: That's it! If you really need to use a field beginning with a double underscore, you can set the synonym name to `_MyMixin__my_field`, or similar.